# Python: Is it possible to set the length of graph edges on pyvis using edge weight as length?

Tags: python

As stated in the subject, I was wondering if it is possible to make edges on pyvis.network show up with the weight of the graph as their actual length. The graph in itself is undirected and around 2000 nodes large, most of which are just intermediate node. If not, are there other libraries that could do the same thing ?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the mass of the nodes, as it is based on a inverted gravity model.

Example

```
nt.add_node(0, mass=5)
```

Comment: This works, but note that mass/gravity will affect a lot more than just tht one node/edge.